# Why can't I toss post variable to PHP when I cover .ajax with function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have 3 files for showing data from myAdmin and it shows no error but after I put function around .ajax, to re-use it, I cannot pass button id to PHP. " Undefined index:  btnId"
What seems wrong?

HTML file, written in PHP (below looped in for code)

```
   print"<button class='refresh' data-name='$btnId' id='$btnId'>{$btnId}</button>";  
   print "<table id='$idForShowNewData' class='showNewData'></table>";
```

show.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.refresh').click(function(){

    $(function showTable() {
　　　　$.ajax({
          url: "show.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "btnId": $(this).data("name")
          },
          success: function(data) {
             //more code
          },
          error: function(xhr,XMLHttpRequest,errorThrown){
             //more code
          }
        });
      });
    showTable();

  });
});
```

PHP file that get's data from myAdmin. Getting id like below is at the top of the script.

```
$gotBtnId = $_POST['btnId'];
```

Comment: Why did you "wrap" `function showTable() { ... }` in `$( )`? `$( <function> )` is the short form of `$(document).ready( <function> )`

Comment: Why is this wrapped into an extra function inside the click handler, why are you not executing the code directly there?

Comment: I want to use the .ajax part few times.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `showTable` refers to `window` object and not the `button` whose `data-name` you want to send in the request.

If you want `showTable` to be invoked when the page is loaded and also be registered as a listener for click events to the refresh button, declare it as follows:

```
   const $refreshBtn = $('button.refresh');
   function showTable() {
      
　　　　$.ajax({
          url: "show.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "btnId": $refreshBtn.data("name")
          },
          success: function(data) {
             //more code
          },
          error: function(xhr,XMLHttpRequest,errorThrown){
             //more code
          }
        });
      });

   $(function() {
      showTable();
      $refreshBtn.click(showTable); 
   });
```